# Trouble getting values of an EventSeries

Tags: time-series

Suppose I have an `EventSeries` and I need to extract the values corresponding to some `DateObject`, taking properly into account the `TimeZone` and possible repetions of dates. I way I considered and probably used in the pas was to "evaluate" the `EventSeries` at the list of dates. Now I'm unable to reproduce this process.

For example consider the code:

```
date = DateObject[]
es = EventSeries[{1}, {{date}}]
es["DatePath"]
es["FirstDate"] === date
(*True*)

es[date]
(*Missing[]*)
```

I also tried

```
Replace[date, Rule @@@ es["DatePath"]]
(*no replacement done*)
```

with no success.

What is the supported way to do the job described?

Please note I have/want/need an `EventSeries`, not a potentially interpolating `TimeSeries`.

### POSSIBLE WORKAROUND 1

```
First /@ Nearest[es["Times"] -> es["Values"], AbsoluteTime /@ {date, date, date}, {1, 0.01}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe it may be a bug. `DateObjects` without a decimal seconds work as expected.

```
date2 = DateObject@{2008, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1}; 
es2 = EventSeries[{1}, {{date2}}]; 
es2[date2]
(* 1 *)
```

However, DateObjects with decimal seconds such as those returned by `DateObject[]` do not cooperate. I suggest reporting it to WRI.

As a workaround you can clean the fractional seconds from the dates before creating the `EventSeries`.

```
date3 = DateObject[];
date3 = date3 /. 
  DateObject[d_, TimeObject[t_, tr___], dr___] :> 
   DateObject[d, TimeObject[Round@t, tr], dr];
es3 = EventSeries[{1}, {{date3}}];
es3[date3]
(* 1 *)
```

Hope this helps.